# Narasimhan-Simha Hermitian metric vs Weil-Petersson metric

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds, weil-petersson-metric

What is relation between Weil-Petersson metric on holomorphic fibre space $f:X\to Y$ of compact complex manifolds $X,Y$ . (let fibres are Calabi-Yau manifolds)

And [Ricci curvature of Narasimhan-Simha Hermitian metric](http://aif.cedram.org/cedram-bin/article/AIF_2016__66_2_753_0.pdf) on direct image of relative line bundle $f_*(K_{X/Y})$.

See : Shigeharu TAKAYAMA
Singularities of Narasimhan-Simha type metrics on direct images of relative
pluricanonical bundles
Tome 66, n
o
2 (2016), p. 753-783.

Comment: I can't see the PDF, but the WP metric can be defined as the curvature form of the natural metric on that pushforward, so its likely those are the same thing, at least when the family is polarized. (See Tian's article on the smoothness of Kuranishi space for Calabi-Yaus.)

Comment: There must be some connection between Narasimhan-Simha Hermitian metric and semi-Ricci flat metric. Tsuji posted some conjectures about it.